# Power AUtomate desktop selector issue

Tags: linkedin-api, selector, power-automate, webautomation

I'm facing an issue in power automation desktop while working on web automation. I'm trying to extract some data from LinkedIn. I'm not able to click on next page button my selectors are showing error. can anyone help me how to fix this issue.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KW9t.png)

Comment: what kind of error? If I see right, you have just posted a sreenshot of part of LI. I can't see any error?

Comment: Hi @Proko I'm unable to extract data from multiple pages, It is not clicking on NEXT, Every time that NEXT button selector is changing. I don't know how to validate it.